# Correção _Coluna_Planilha

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, syntax-error, planilha, passagem-por-valor

Preciso de uma ajuda. estou em um codigo que tem a proposito de corrigir uma coluna especifica de uma planilha. a coluna original vem com os valores acompanhados da letyra D e C , Debito e credito. o codigo retira as letras. Nos  valores creditos é retirado o codigo retira a letra C e nos valores Debitos o codigo retira a letra D e joga o sinal negativo antes do numero. no final ele converte os valores em numerico. O Problema é que em algumas planilha o codigo funciona em outras ao escolher a coluna desejada ele reporta um erro com o Nome da coluna. já conferi se a digitação do nome da coluna está correto, mas ainda sim o erro continua.

import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, simpledialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

def processar_planilha(coluna_selecionada):
# Abrir uma janela de diálogo para selecionar o arquivo
filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename()

```
# Verificar se o arquivo foi selecionado
if filepath:
    try:
        # Carregar a planilha
        df = pd.read_excel(filepath)

        # Substituir 'D' por '-' à esquerda do número e remover 'C' na coluna selecionada
        df[coluna_selecionada] = '-' + df[coluna_selecionada].astype(str).str.replace('D', '').str.replace('C', '')

        # Formatar a coluna selecionada como moeda
        df[coluna_selecionada] = df[coluna_selecionada].apply(lambda x: locale.currency(str(x), grouping=True))

        # Formatar as demais colunas como números
        for coluna in df.columns:
            if coluna != coluna_selecionada:
                df[coluna] = pd.to_numeric(df[coluna], errors='coerce')

        # Salvar a planilha modificada
        savepath = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.xlsx')
        if savepath:
            df.to_excel(savepath, index=False)
            messagebox.showinfo("Sucesso", "Planilha modificada e salva com sucesso!")
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Erro", f"Ocorreu um erro: {str(e)}")
```

## Criar uma janela principal

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Processamento de Planilha")

## Carregar a imagem de fundo

image = Image.open("icone (1).png")
background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

## Configurar o tamanho da janela de acordo com a imagem

root.geometry(f"{background_image.width()}x{background_image.height()}")

## Adicionar a imagem de fundo à janela

background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

## Função para abrir e processar a planilha

def abrir_processar_planilha():
# Pedir ao usuário para selecionar a coluna desejada
coluna_selecionada = simpledialog.askstring("Coluna", "Digite o nome da coluna desejada:")

```
# Chamar a função para processar a planilha
processar_planilha(coluna_selecionada)
```

## Botão para abrir e processar a planilha

btn_processar_planilha = tk.Button(root, text="Abrir e Processar Planilha", command=abrir_processar_planilha)
btn_processar_planilha.pack(pady=10)

## Executar o loop principal da interface gráfica

root.mainloop()

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.